# Rails slow between 6.0.1 and 5.1.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been working on a project using rails 5.1.7 (ruby 2.4.1) on Windows 10 (WSL2) and decided to start a new project with rails 6.0.1 (ruby 2.6.3). On my rails 5.1.7 app, resetting my database using `rails db:{drop,create,migrate,seed}` and starting the server with `rails s` both ran just fine (maybe 10 seconds total from start to finish). My rails 6.0.1 app, however, easily takes 30 seconds to run those commands despite being a brand new app and running spring.

Comment: Noticing a similar thing. Test suite takes about 4x longer to run. Still early days here so nothing more concrete than that but was expecting a slight speed up, not a dramatic slow down.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails 6 is no quite a stable version. Some gems needs to be upgraded to this version of Rails and it might take a bit more of time. In fact the performance of your rails app will depend on how your Database is will executed and the amount of JS or front end libraries your using.

But to try debbuging your app issue I would recommend **uninstall some gems and install them again**, which some can leave cache over your code environment. Despite this I would rather recommend you this nice blog,
https://www.railsspeed.com/ which it talks about get your rails app to a better performance.

Hope it works!
Cheers

Comment: The gems are not the issue as this this a brand new rails app with all of the default gems provided by `rails new my_app`. I have even removed those gems and got the same results.